# how can view data from refcursor in pgadmin postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Im a new bies in postgresql and pgadmin.
I have function and call it. The result like this

```
SELECT board_getallboardcontents(1,1,true,30,1,'KO',1,1,'2016-01-01','2019-06-30',0,false,false)
```

Result of data.

> unnamed portal 3
>
> unnamed portal 4

How can see data from

> unnamed portal 3
>
> unnamed portal 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a transaction, you would call the stored procedure and [retrieve](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) the data from the cursor

```
-- Start a transaction
BEGIN;

  SELECT board_getallboardcontents(1,1,true,30,1,'KO',1,1,'2016-01-01','2019-06-30',0,false,false);

  FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 3>";
  FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 4>";
COMMIT;
```

This [tutorial](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure) is relevant

Comment: Thank but it give me error: ERROR:  cursor "<unnamed portal 3>" does not exis

ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 3>" does not exist
SQL state: 34000